# Mark XML empty nodes as unimportant in BeyondCompare

Tags: beyondcompare3

When using BeyondCompare I want to mark the XML empty node difference as unimportant.

<country /> and <country></country> are functionally the same, and I want to hide this difference

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Please visit the support forums for BeyondCompare for this: http://www.scootersoftware.com/vbulletin/ . Feel free to post the solution here though.

Answer (score 0):

Go to rules replacements
and following settings

[image]